# Android payment gateway error in webivew

Tags: java, android, payment-gateway, android-developer-api, razorpay

I trying to build my web application to webview and everything is going fine but I have a problem while making payment. I get this error:

INFO: CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "https://api.razorpay.com" from accessing a frame with origin "https://www.kinre.in". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.", source: https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout-frame.js (1)

Comment: WebView does not let to use frames with different domain.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin from accessing a cross-origin frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame)

Comment: have you found any solution? 'm facing the same here.

Comment: any solution for this?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @SuryaMahla even u have the same issue?

Comment: @SunishaSindhu Yes, I have a webview where I am integrating Razorpay but getting this error and because of that payment window is not opening. Everything is working in my website(no error, payment is being completed) but when I use webview to convert it into an app, payment won't work. Can you help me out here?

Comment: @SuryaMahla for me also am facing same issue..I don't know what to do...And I couldn't find any solution for this

Comment: @SuryaMahla did you find any solution for this?